# Why can't I answer a protected question?

Tags: support, protected-questions

> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam
>   answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10
>   reputation on this site.

As you can see, I have 101 reputation, and yet I can't answer the [question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/49991/40110).

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have earned 10 reputation **on this site** in order to provide an answer to the question.

Although you have 101 rep overall you have not contributed any upvoted content to the site so have not received any reputation here. This is because every Stack Exchange site is different and has different requirements of answers. Just because you may have decent reputation on one site that doesn't mean you know the ins-and-outs of how *every* site on Stack Exchange works.

Very popular questions, such as the one linked to are often protected because they tend to attract low-quality posts, spam or answers that should really be comments so the post is protected to keep the quality of the answers up.

For this reason we have protected the question. If you can get yourself 10 rep on this site (and that's not really so hard - just an upvoted answer on any other question should do it) then you'll be able to leave an answer on that post. But once you've done so be sure that your answer is not just a variation on those that have already been left. That question attracts a lot of "I prefer option B because it looks nicer" type answers (hence the protection status), which aren't really much help to the OP or any future visitors.

Comment: So why don't the 100 points for being "trusted" on another stackexchange site count?  I thought the point was to give you a head start so you _could_ just hit the ground running.

Comment: ... and just to clarify, my answer for that post is actually totally different than all the answers there.  They are all missing something obvious.

Comment: This was implemented due to a request made on metaStackOverflow a few years back - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109117/can-the-protect-feature-be-made-to-block-101-users-as-well

Comment: If your answer to that question is a useful and different one then I look forward to reading it - but you'll still need to leave an answer elsewhere on this site that gets upvoted before you have sufficient rep to answer that question. We can't unprotect it yet - you should see the answers / posts / comments that *have* been left on that post that have since been deleted - and are the reason for the question protection.

Comment: I went ahead and answered another question and got my 10 points, so I could answer the protected question.  [Here's my answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/50100/40110)